# Need to know my login in local SQL Server

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, authentication

I forgot my "Name" and "User" field. Remember only password. So i can work with SQL, but i can't connect SQL to my Java project in intellij idea. How can i know "Name" and "User" field?
[screen IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbpp3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can connect with some SQL tool, where you will probably have stored userid and password somewhere so that you don't have to type them everytime you connect.

If it's a database that supports the ANSI pseudo column `user`, just type:

```
SELECT user;
```

Or, in Oracle, for example:

```
SELECT user FROM dual;
```

It will return the name of the user that is currently logged in.

Hope this helps ...

Marco